# Passing both a file resource and a json body in a single HTTP POST request

Tags: php, json, laravel, http, curl

I'm building a REST API and I have an endpoint where I need to pass both a file resource, and a JSON body. Apparently I cannot do it:

```
You can only select one HTTP request method! You asked for both POST.
```

I'm getting this error when in cURL request I provide both form field and a body like this:

```
curl -X POST "http://127.0.0.1/path" -F "resource=@img.jpg" -d "@requestBody.json"
```

If I want this to work, I need to pass my request body as a form field itself:

```
curl -X POST "http://127.0.0.1/path" -F "resource=@img.jpg" -F "myRequestBody=@requestBody.json;type=application/json"
```

The thing is that in order to fetch this down the line, I need to use `file_get_contents()` function and then json decode the content as well. It's not a nice solution, and it seems a bit slow. Is there a cleaner way to do it?

Comment: When you upload a file, shouldn't the content type be `multipart/form-data`?

Comment: I think cURL adds it automatically when it detects `-F` parameter though

Comment: Not sure if it would override the type when you are explicitly mentioning `type=application/json`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how big the file is, you could base64 encode the data and include that in your JSON payload.

Otherwise, you will need to use `Content-Type: multipart/form-data`.